# What is the variable scope in if statement in karate tfw?

Tags: testing, karate

Can you help me to understand the scope of the variables in if statement?

```
 * def a = "a"
 * if ( 1 == 1 ) a = "b"
 * print "a--",a

 * def str =
      """
      <tag>#(a)</tag>
      """
 * print "str--",str
```

```
output : 
[print] a-- a
[print] str-- <tag>b</tag>
```

When I use `karate.set('a',"b")` instead of just `a = "b"` then the output looks correct.

```
[print] a-- b
[print] str-- <tag>b</tag>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The JS engine was made slightly better in the 1.0 RC, we are focusing on that right now: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/1.0-upgrade-guide

```
* def a = "a"
* if (true) a = "b"
* print "a:", a
* def str = <tag>#(a)</tag>
* print "str:", str
```

And the output is:

```
[print] a: b 
[print] str: <tag>b</tag>
```

So as a general rule we want JS and Karate `def` variables to co-exist seamlessly. The old version did have some gaps where variables tended to be local with JS blocks. And you are right, use `karate.set()` where needed. This is very useful when for e.g. you are within a re-usable function or the `configure headers` function and you want to set or modify a "global" variable.